# Problem calling activity from another package in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, package, manifest

Situation:
I need to combine several apps into one .apk app. Lets say implement app2 into app1

What i have done:
Copied app2 package into main app1 project which i am working, so my app1 has two packages.

app2 had this manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.package.app2" android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.2">

<application android:label="App2" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="Activity1" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>        

<activity android:name="Activity2" android:excludeFromRecents="true"></activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

My original App1 manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
package="com.package.app1">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".Start" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.package.app1.PlayerList" />
    <activity android:name="com.package.app1.CreateNewPlayer" />
    <activity android:name="com.package.app1.Profile" />                       
    <activity android:name="com.package.app1.Braintrainer" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

The code in app1 i am using to call activity in app2 package:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.package.app1", "com.package.app2.Activity1");                    
startActivity(i);
```

The question:
How do i modify my app1 manifest file to have activities of app2.

Things i`ve tried:
It works if i create simple HelloWorld test class in app2, call using the same code and just include this in the app1 manifest:

```
        <activity android:name="com.package.app2.Test" />
```

But i can not figure out how to implement the app2 manifest file into the first one. Every way i try give no errors but crashes when calling that activity. App2 alone works fine, so problem not in the activity file.

Appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.package.app1", "com.package.app2.Activity1");                    
startActivity(i);
```

Shot in the dark:

change `com.package.app1` to `com.package.app2`. I've called done what you're attempting right now, and I've always had to specify the package of the class I wanted to call.

Ok, PackageManager is not your solution, I misread and thought you had two apps and wanted one app to call the other. It looks like you just want one app.

Modify your app1's manifest like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
package="com.package.app1">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".Start" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.package.app2.Activity1" />
    <activity android:name="com.package.app2.Activity2" android:excludeFromRecents="true"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.package.app1.PlayerList" />
    <activity android:name="com.package.app1.CreateNewPlayer" />
    <activity android:name="com.package.app1.Profile" />                       
    <activity android:name="com.package.app1.Braintrainer" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

And try the first way again.

Comment: no, of i change it to app2 it doesn`t work even with a simple test class, if i call with setComponent then yeah its app2, but doesn`t change anything since it works with test clas as well but not with app2 class. isn`t it something to do with manifest file?

Comment: package manager sounds like a solution, what about the manifest files in this case? also how do i choose which activity in com.package.app2 package to open in yoru example, if the package does not have a manifest file when copied into my project

Comment: thats what i`m asking, if i use simple HelloWorld class in app2 and just add  <activity android:name="com.package.app2.Test" /> to my app1 manifest file it works, but i don`t know how to add app2 manifest activities into the first one. if just add all activities with their content filters it crashes

Comment: didn`t work, seems like another solution is just copying the files into one single package and try running everything as a single application. Is there any other ways to combine several apps into one .apk file ?

Comment: What was the erorr in your logcat?

Comment: ok so the problem is in a different place. i renamed the package before, by using refactor -> rename, also right click on the project and Rename Application Package, but in logcat i see ClassNotFoundException looking for the actiity using old package name. any ideas how to change the package name properly?

Comment: got it work! problem was in XML file, there was some hardcoded package name written in the layout file - bad practise

Answer (score 0):

I have several packages and need to do something similar in my app.

You need to be careful with this technique, otherwise you'll experience nasty memory leaks.

I declared my activity in my base controller (activity) class as a static variable.  All controller classes inherit from this class, so all controller classes are able to access it.  Pass in the activity as an argument for anything outside of the controller classes that need to access the activity.