# call intent from another package in android...?

Tags: android, android-intent, package

I have two package with different class.
ex.
com.app.abc1,
com.app.abc2

now I want to call abc2 package's xyz2 class from abc1 package's xyz1 class. So I wrote below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(xyz1.this, com.app.abc2.xyz2.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

but it crash my app

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874218/problem-calling-activity-from-another-package-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
Intent int_b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), class_b.class);
```

`startActivity(int_b);
finish();`

Don't forget to add your activity in Manifest file.. like this..

```
<activity android:name="com.example.class_b">  </activity>
```

Hope helped!

Answer (score 0):

did u declare ur second activity in manifest file ?

if so, u must specify the package path there itself. no need to specify it in **Intent**.

```
package="com.app"
<activity
        android:name=".abc1.xyz1"/ >
<activity
        android:name=".abc2.xyz2"/ >
Intent intent = new Intent(xyz1.this, xyz2.class);
                 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                 startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
```